# Installing the traffic manager Ambassador Agent on multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, telepresence

I have a large cluster with several namespaces -

```
+------------------------ test-cluster ---------------------+
|                                                           |
| +---------+    +---------+    +---------+    +---------+  |
| | default |    |  alpha  |    |  beta   |    | ...     |  |
| +---------+    +---------+    +---------+    +---------+  |
|                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to install the telepresence `helm` chart for each individual namespace.

I can install it on the first namespace (`alpha`) -

```bash
$ helm install traffic-manager datawire/telepresence -n alpha -f values.yml
```

And I can confirm the release is successful and installed:

```bash
$ helm list -n alpha | grep traffic | awk '{ print $1 }'
traffic-manager
```

However, when I try to install it on the second namespace (`beta`), I get -

```bash
$ helm install traffic-manager datawire/telepresence -n beta -f values.yml
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "traffic-manager-ambassador-agent" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "beta": current value is "alpha"
```

It seems that the `ClusterRole` is not created *per namespace* and is instead shared. It is "owned" by `alpha` since it was installed there first.

The `values.yml` file looks like -

```yaml
clientRbac:
  create: true
  namespaced: true
  namespaces:
    - beta
  subjects:
    - kind: Group
      name: eks-user
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
managerRbac:
  create: true
  namespaced: true
  namespaces:
    - beta
```

Comment: That's true, ClusterRoles are cluster-global objects.  A couple of other objects like Namespaces and PersistentVolumes are as well.  Can you change the ClusterRole name to include both the release name and the namespace (and still fit within the general 63-character object-name limit)?

Comment: @DavidMaze - Thanks. Looking at the telepresence helm chart, I don't see any option relating to the `ClusterRole`s created. Is that the only place to configure this? (https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/tree/release/v2/charts/telepresence)